# Can a video calling app overlay in iOS?

Tags: iphone

I switched from Android to iOS; in Android, when I was using the Video Calling Apps, there was an overlay feature, which helped me do other things while on the video call. But, I am not able to do the same on iOS. Is there some setting, or is this not possible in iOS?

Edit: I was using Google meet (formerly Duo), and the call doesn't drop instead, the video drops. Like the other person isn't able to see my video, I am also unable to see theirs. Earlier in Andriod, a small box used to appear that showed their video.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Does the call drop if you navigate to another app while in a video call? Which app are you using?

Comment: @nohillside No, the call doesn't drop like I am using the google meet app (Duo earlier); the camera just switches off. Earlier in Andriod, a small window used to appear when I switched to other apps, and it showed the other person and also my video was visible to them. So, I can talk in the video call with them, while using other apps. Now, my video just switches off when I change apps.